# InvalidOperationException: Cannot find reference assembly 'System.AppContext.dll' file for package System.AppContext.Reference

Tags: asp.net-core

I've created a new project using ASP.Net Core 2 project targeting .Net framework 4.7.1 and I see the following error on startup.

"InvalidOperationException: Cannot find reference assembly 'System.AppContext.dll' file for package System.AppContext.Reference".

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add reference to following Nuget Package to resolve this error.

Package:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation

Comment: It won't resolve an issue if you don't need a view compilation to be OFF. It works only if view compilation is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation from Microsoft, the fix for this problem is adding the following package reference to your web project:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

Comment: Note that this is the fix if you DON'T use view compilation. If you do, just remove the PrivateAssets part